# Call a restful service by passing it a value given by a user?

Tags: c#, rest

I have a restful service in my local host that I want to call and get the returned value from. It returns a string and it takes in an int (zip code) as its parameter. To call it you need to do the following:

`http://localhost:49842/WCFRest/Service.svc/deliverable?x={zipCode}`

Where `zipCode` is the int that I want to pass it. When I use a default zip code it returns me this :

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
some return string.
</string>
```

So how would I go about passing it a value from a text box and then save what it returns as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's get this done with shall we? :)
 so you give your input tag an id, say id="zipcodeinput"
and in your javascript file, (after you link your jquery) you can write something like this.

You could take the value of the zip code directly after your client passes in his zip code

```
$("#zipcodeinput").on("keyup", function() {
 var zipvalue = $(this).val();
}
```

// you take the zip value directly after the client passes any number/numbers from your input

```
if(zipvalue.length <=4){
 return;
}
```

// here you check if the zip code is more than 4 numbers (here you say how long do you want your zip code, maybe more or less depending on your country zip) if it's less than 4 numbers stop the script and start again until you write 5 numbers or more

you can after use your zip code variable (zipvalue) in your string. I would've sent json object instead but its up to you :)
anyways you would specify your url that you're getting or sending to be something like this.

```
url:"http://localhost:49842/WCFRest/Service.svc/deliverable?x=" + zipvalue
```

something like this approach i would think of.

Cheers!